# Method `crypto.randomBytes()` in Node.js generates more bytes than specify in parameter `size`?

Tags: node.js, random, cryptography

I have Node.js v6.3.1. Why the next code generates two characters instead of one?

```
crypto.randomBytes( 1 ).toString('hex')
```

Is one byte encodes two characters? Is it possible bug? ([docs for randomBytes()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback))

Comment: Next time, try to localize the issue; try a byte with different values (without using the `randomBytes` method) and call `toString('hex')` on it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, method `randomBytes` return buffer; how can I more localize issue, write `'s'.toString('hex')`? This code return just `'s'`. And how this interpret now?

Comment: I'm sure you can create a 1 byte buffer somehow? What you are creating above is a (character) string. Try and look into encoding and character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One byte is expressed in hexadecimal encoding as two characters, each in the range of 0-9a-f (upper or lower case). Each characters represents 4-bits.

Hexadecimal (hex) is generally used to represent binary data, some or most 8-bit values, depending on the character encoding, can not be represented as printable characters. As an example the byte with the bits `00000111` is represented as `07` in hex, it is the bell character so it can't print.

See [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).